# Unable to install TypeScript in Visual Studio 2012 Professional update 3

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation, typescript

I'm unable to install/use TypeScript (version 0.9.1.1) in Visual Studio 2012 Professional update 4 on a Windows 7 machine.

After "successful install" TypeScript doesn't show in the Tools, Extension and Updates. I'm not able to add a new item with .ts extension to an MVC4 project. When I try to add a .ts file, VS adds a .cs file.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the templates were installed; just hard to find.

Add > New Item, then search for Typescript in the top-right search box. Came up with the "TypeScript file" type.

Since Web Essentials dropped the support to compile ts files to js files, I found this link helpful: http://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Compile-on-Save

I didn't have to do the following first step as it was already in the csproj file.

```
<TypeScriptCompile Include="MyFile.ts" />
```

After unloading the MVC project, I'd to add the following at the end of the csproj file (still within the project element):

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
<TypeScriptTarget>ES3</TypeScriptTarget>
<TypeScriptRemoveComments>false</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
<TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap>
<TypeScriptModuleKind>AMD</TypeScriptModuleKind>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
<TypeScriptTarget>ES3</TypeScriptTarget>
<TypeScriptRemoveComments>true</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
<TypeScriptSourceMap>false</TypeScriptSourceMap>
<TypeScriptModuleKind>AMD</TypeScriptModuleKind>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" />
```

MyFile.ts was in the /scripts folder. I added a script reference to the file in my view:

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/MyFile.js"></script>
}
```

Everything worked at this point.